# Set Users to not be Challenged for Credentials?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2000

How can I restrict my users to stop getting Log in / accessed into my Database by Enterprise Manager or by any other way in SQL Server 2000?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to provide more details of the scenario you're trying to support, but you can put a database into single user mode to allow one and only one user in (your admin account for example).  As part of this, you can force existing connections closed.

Answer (score 1):

Make allow remote connections set to false.